# Windows 7 Python 3.2 file not found on open

Tags: python, windows, file-io, python-3.x

I have the following Python 3.2 script:

```
f = open('C:/foo/bar/baz/text.txt')
```

this causes a file not found exception:

```
ileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/foo/bar/baz/text.txt'
```

However taking that same path and pasting it into Windows explorer opens the file just fine.  What am I missing within my environment on Windows 7?

Comment: It's worth noting you should always use the ``with`` statement when dealing with files to ensure they are closed properly (even on exceptions).

Comment: Turns out it was text.txt.txt

Comment: @Woot4Moo in that case, I believe you should delete this question. I don't believe this helps anyone, it looks like a typo (you were using a wrong file name). Anyway, I'm glad you figured it out, these little mistakes sometimes are a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue after running `icacls` on the command line:

The file that `icacls` finds was actually `text.txt.txt` .  The odd part was that windows was still able to find it.

Comment: You have 'show file extensions' turned off. Windows still detects that this file exists because you have this option enabled. You did NOT 'make sure the file exists' as you said, nor did 'text.txt' actually exist as you claimed

Comment: @jsvk Incorrect the file showed up in explorer, I have been programming long enough to validate that a file does indeed exist before coming to SO.  However, when the file is displayed via explorer it implies the file is there.

Comment: But you *didn't* verify it exists. Explorer displays 'text.txt' instead of 'text.txt.txt' because you have file extensions hidden, an aesthetic feature present on later versions of windows. The file listed was *not* text.txt, even if it displays in explorer that way. You'll notice other files, like "setup.exe", may display as "setup". That doesn't mean the filename is "setup"

Comment: It's an understandable mistake, however, I don't think this question is really useful to anyone any more, you might want to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you should try something like:

```
f = open(r'C:\foo\bar\baz\text.txt')
```

Comment: This works on my Windows 7 professional, but fails on Windows 7 Home

Comment: @Lattyware can't even test, I am on ubuntu.

Comment: @Woot4Moo are you sure do you've the exact path in your win7 home?

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/foo/bar/baz/text.txt'`

Comment: @Woot4Moo try this :`open(r'C:\foo\bar\baz\text.txt')`, not your code `open('C:/foo/bar/baz/text.txt')`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that also fails.

Comment: @Woot4Moo this is weird, win7 home and professional have the same file systems, and if the file exists and the path is correct then it should work.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary it turns out it was `text.txt.txt` I guess windows allows for a shortcut where you don't need to include the extension

Answer (score 0):

You should use double backslash in the path instead of slash.

Comment: also fails, i think the double slash only applies to forward.

Comment: The single forward slash should work fine, and @Woot4Moo no, you escape backslashes in the path, not forward. It's either `C:/folder/file` or `C:\\folder\\file`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `C:\foo\bar\baz\text.txt` exists